# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS stuck on 800x600 resolution

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, display-resolution

Complete Ubuntu newb here but I have a business requirement for running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS non-GUI and am trying to get up to speed.

My hardware is a brand new Intel i5 NUC.

I have a program which I've installed and is set up as a separate user which automatically logs in when the PC boots up and runs the display.

The issue I'm having is that the resolution is stuck on 800x600 and any xrandr or glxinfo command I attempt returns 'Can't open display'

I've looked around and can see people have fixed it by upgrading Ubuntu or uninstalling graphics card drivers but neither of these apply here and I have to use Ubuntu 18.

My aim is to change the orientation of the screen to portrait and have it outputting at 1080x1920 but for now I'm stuck on landscape @ 800 x 600.

Any assistance you can provide will be invaluable and I thank you in advance.

Comment: By "non-GUI" you mean you're running Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server does not use the X windowing system, so `xrandr` and `glxinfo` will not work for you. That said, you should be able to accomplish this with a little help from `fbcon` (frame buffer control) and some edits to your Grub file.

First, let's rotate the screen. This can be done at any time while the system is running, so let's get the rotation index that you'll need:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate
```

Using `1` in the command above will rotate your screen clockwise. There are four options available:

| Value | Action |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | Normal rotation |
| `1` | Rotate clockwise |
| `2` | Rotate upside-down |
| `3` | Rotate counter-clockwise |

You'll probably want `1` or `3` depending on how your screen is rotated.

Once you know which option you want, you can edit your Grub configuration file to include this orientation at startup:

0. Edit the Grub file as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use the editor of your choice. It does not need to be* `vi`.
1. Add the rotation to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fbcon=rotate:1"
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to change* `1` *to the proper rotation index.*
2. Save the file
3. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Your orientation will now default to the rotation index you have chosen.

Next, let's look at the resolution. You will need to reboot and do a bit of work with Grub, so hopefully you're not doing this with a production server during operation hours.

0. Reboot your machine
1. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after the BIOS/UEFI has finished to bring up Grub
2. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to for the Grub command line
3. Type `videoinfo` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   ***Note:** If you get a "Command not found" error, use `vbeinfo` instead.
4. Identify the supported video mode that you want to use. For example, you might see something like:

   ```
   Mode 0x0366: 1920x1080 (+1920), 8 bits
   Mode 0x0367: 1920x1080 (+3840), 16 bits
   Mode 0x0368: 1920x1080 (+7680), 24 bits
   ```

   It's the `0x0368`-type value that you need.
5. Reboot back into Ubuntu

Now let's add some more values to the Grub file:

0. Edit the Grub file as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use the editor of your choice. It does not need to be* `vi`.
1. Add the `video` and `gfxpayload` flags to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. **⇠ DO NOT REMOVE ANY VALUES THAT MIGHT ALREADY EXIST IN THE LINE. SIMPLY APPEND THESE.**

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=0x0368 gfxpayload=true"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=0x0368 gfxpayload=true"
   ```
2. Uncomment the `GRUB_GFXMODE` line if required, and set the resolution to the value that matches your desired setting:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x24
   ```
3. Add two more `GRUB_GFX` items:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1920x1080x24
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080x24
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Reboot

This should give you exactly what you're looking for.